# Cannot run python script with pyautogui as Cron job

Tags: python-3.x, cron, pyautogui

I've been looking as various ways to fix this issue but cannot find anything that works.

I can see that the script is running by debugging yet the pyautogui function is not running via Cron. I can confirm the script runs as expected via cli and that the pyautogui module can be seen by cron.

This is what my cron job looks like for testing.

```
* * * * * cd /Users/joeblogs && python3 ./mouse.py >> /Users/joeblogs/debug.txt 2>&1
```

This the my script i'm using, it's a very simple script that checks the mouse coordinates then wait 5 seconds and checks again. If the coordinates match the the mouse is moved via pyautogui, if they don't match then the program exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyautogui
import time
import sys

def MovMouse():

        prev = pyautogui.position() #Grabs X,Y mouse position
        #print("position X1 is", prev[0])
        #print("position Y1 is", prev[1])

        time.sleep(5)

        after = pyautogui.position() #Grabs second X,Y position after 3 seconds

        #print("position X2 is", after[0])
        #print("position Y2 is", after[1])

        if (prev == after):
            print ("!!! MOVE MOUSE !!!")
            pyautogui.moveRel(200, 200)
            #postmove = pyautogui.position
            #print("position X3 is", postmove[0])
            #print("position Y3 is", postmove[1])
        else:
            print("Mouse does not need to be moved")
            sys.exit(0)


MovMouse()
```

I've looked at similar posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805988/how-to-make-crontab-run-a-python-script-that-opens-the-terminal-and-does-stuff/54806497) but no joy.

Any help would be great as this issue has been bugging me for a while!

FYI I'm using the latest version of python3 as of writing this and running in MacOS.

**Solved - I needed to allow accessibility access to cron and my terminal in MacOS settings and now it's working as expexted!**

Answer (score 0):

**Solved - I needed to allow accessibility access to cron and my terminal in MacOS settings and now it's working as expexted!**